# How to grouped the following variable and command and read 1 by 1

Tags: bash, scripting, variable, for

I've following array and variable :

```
httpurl="http://www.nnin.com"
firstquery=$(curl -s -X POST -d "UID=user1&PWD=1111" $httpurl)
name="firstcust"
ip="105.105.0.1"

httpurl="http://www.mmim.com"
secondquery=$(curl -s -X POST -d "UID=user2&PWD=2222" $httpurl)
name="secondcust"
ip="106.106.0.1"

httpurl="http://www.ooio.com"
thirdquery=$(curl -s -X POST -d "UID=user3&PWD=3333" $httpurl)
name="thirdcust"
ip="107.107.0.1"
```

below is the code I use :-

```
httpurl="http://www.nnin.com"
firstquery=$(curl -s -X POST -d "UID=user1&PWD=1111" $httpurl)
name="firstcust"
ip="105.105.0.1"

status=$?

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "$name : $ip (success)"
    exit $status
else
    echo "$name : $ip (failed)"
    exit $status
fi
```

how do I grouped the query&variable? (the variable `$status` stored the error code for `curl` command). How do i make the code read each of the following query&variable and print the output (someone suggest I use `for`)
and move to next query&variable. the purpose of this script to check the return code from the following url and print the output `Success for 0` and `failed for non-zero`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use some thing like:

```
httpurl[0]="http://www.nnin.com"
query[0]="curl -s -X POST -d 'UID=user1&PWD=1111'"
name[0]="firstcust"
ip[0]="105.105.0.1"

httpurl[1]="http://www.mmim.com"
query[1]="curl -s -X POST -d 'UID=user2&PWD=2222'"
name[1]="secondcust"
ip[1]="106.106.0.1"

httpurl[1]="http://www.ooio.com"
query[1]="curl -s -X POST -d 'UID=user3&PWD=3333'"
name[1]="thirdcust"
ip[1]="107.107.0.1"

for i in 0 1 2
  do

    ${query[$i]) ${httpurl[$i]}

    status=$?

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "${name[$i]} : ${ip[$i]} (success)"
        #exit $status
    else
        echo "${name[$i]} : ${ip[$i]} (failed)"
        #exit $status
    fi
  done
```

**Reference:** [Bash Reference Manual - Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays)

Comment: when i run the script...I only get 1 Success,it supposed to get 3 Success right? (bcos of the 3 `curl` cmd)

Comment: @Asif, It depend how you want to handle failures. Better to call `exit` after the loop.

Comment: i've succeed...thnks btw..really helped a lot..